# Bootstrap 4 Carousel responsive img overlay

Tags: responsive-design, carousel, bootstrap-4

Can some one please help.

Trying to put a company logo overplayed on a bootstrap 4 carousel, so that when the image slides the company logo remains in the same place.

Trying to avoid Java and editing the photo so they have the logo on will not have the desired effect.

I can get it to show with main pitch div, but only if i give the image a defined width, ie not a percentage. This then stops it being responsive. which again doesnt have the desired effect.

CSS is standard here is the HTML.

If anyone could help that would be great.

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="carousel-item active">
<img class="d-block w-100" src="images/bluekitchen.jpg" alt="First slide">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<img class="d-block w-100" src="images/greykitchen.jpg" alt="Second slide">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<img class="d-block w-100" src="images/kitchentable.jpg" alt="Third slide">
</div>
</div>

<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>

<div class="mainPitch" style="position:absolute; top:40%; left: 40%;">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="fixedcaption">
<img class="mx-auto d-block" src="images/greenwelllogotext.svg" style="width: 15em;" alt=""/>      
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of posting the same question again, [improve the existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706466/bootstrap-4-carousel-with-responsive-image-overlay).

Comment: I tried to re-phrase as to not confuse people, added code, How else could I improve the question? On the first question, you commented asking for code, which I have provide. With that insight are you now able to answer my question?